# Enviar headers em HTTP Request com cURL no PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, libcurl, http-headers

Olá, fiz uma função para fazer chamadas cURL à uma API e estou conseguindo fazer as chamadas porém não estou conseguindo enviar headers.

**Função:**

```
    function curlRequest($endpoint, $verb, $headers, $params = null) {
    try {
        //Inicia o cURL
        $ch = curl_init();

        //URL da API
        $url = API_URL . $endpoint;

        if (isset($params)) {
            $fields = http_build_query($params);
        }

        //Trata o verbo
        if ($verb === 'POST' || $verb === 'PUT' || $verb === 'DELETE') {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

            if ($verb == 'POST') {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            } else if ($verb == 'PUT') {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
            } else {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'DELETE');
            }
        }

        //CURL Options
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
            CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => true
        ));

       //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
       //var_dump($headers);
       //die();

        //Pega o retorno
        $jsonRetorno = curl_exec($ch);

        //Decodifica o JSON
        $arrayRetorno = json_decode($jsonRetorno, true);

        //Retorna o Array
        return $arrayRetorno;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'O seguinte erro ocorreu ao fazer requisição aos servidores: ' . $e->getMessage();
    } finally {
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

Fiz um vardump das informações do curl e o header aparenta estar vazio.

```
    /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/web/application/helpers/funcoes_helper.php:41:
    array (size=26)
      'url' => string 'api.mydomain.net/usuario/autenticar' (length=39)
      'content_type' => null
      'http_code' => int 0
      'header_size' => int 0
      'request_size' => int 0
      'filetime' => int 0
      'ssl_verify_result' => int 0
      'redirect_count' => int 0
      'total_time' => float 0
      'namelookup_time' => float 0
      'connect_time' => float 0
      'pretransfer_time' => float 0
      'size_upload' => float 0
      'size_download' => float 0
      'speed_download' => float 0
      'speed_upload' => float 0
      'download_content_length' => float -1
      'upload_content_length' => float -1
      'starttransfer_time' => float 0
      'redirect_time' => float 0
      'redirect_url' => string '' (length=0)
      'primary_ip' => string '' (length=0)
      'certinfo' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'primary_port' => int 0
      'local_ip' => string '' (length=0)
      'local_port' => int 0
    /opt/lampp/htdocs/projetos/soccerama/web/application/helpers/funcoes_helper.php:40:
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'Content-Type: application/json' (length=30)
  1 => string 'xAuthClienteID: 2' (length=17)
  2 => string 'xAuthChaveApi: 3851b1ae73ca0ca6e3c24a0256a80ace' (length=47)
  3 => string 'login: admin' (length=12)
  4 => string 'senha: teste' (length=12)
```

Estou fazendo algo errado? Existe outra forma de enviar os headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente isso ocorre porque a array está formatado de maneira errada. O `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` espera um array do tipo:

```
['Content-Type: application/json', 'Qualquer: Coisa'];
```

Cada valor da array deve ser uma linha, seguindo o padrão dos cabeçalhos (`Nome: Valor`). Para comparação, você está fazendo isso uma array associativa entre o nome do cabeçalho e seu valor:

```
['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Qualquer' => 'Coisa'];
```

Isto não é suportado, *ao menos até onde eu sei.*

---

Uma solução para *converter* a array seria um `foreach`:

```
$arr = ['Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Qualquer' => 'Coisa'];

$h = [];
foreach($arr as $nome => $valor){
     $h[] = $nome . ': '. $valor;
}
```

*Utilize `$h` como argumento para o `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.*

Comment: Eu mudei a estrutura do array como pode ser visto no código editado. Mesmo assim o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Você está dando o `var_dump` antes do `curl_exec`, ele não tem como pegar as informações corretas. Execute o curl e dê o var_dump depois e veja os valores do `request_header` ou dê um `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ));`, também após o `exec`.

Comment: Aparentemente não há nenhum problema.

Comment: Tem razão, não sei como pude deixar passar isso. Além disso quando eu seto o parâmetro 'CURLOPT_HEADER => true' o valor retorna null. Mas obrigado pela ajuda.